# Change "Active" icon on selected NavigationPage when using TabbedPage

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm very, very new to Xamarin.Forms. My task, if it is possible, and I'm not sure if it is, is to change our icon from the default blue when it is active.

[image]

I was given icons that are orange and they would like to display those or at least the color instead of the default blue. Again, I'm not sure if this is possible.

This is the code I'm using for the tabbed page.

```
public class LandingPage : TabbedPage
{
    public LandingPage ()
    {
         NavigationPage homepage = new NavigationPage (new CarouselPage {
                Title = "Title",
                Children = {
                  //code removed 
                }
        });

        NavigationPage eventspage = new NavigationPage (new ContentPage {
                Title = "Calendar Event List",
                Content = new EventList ()
        });
        NavigationPage morepage = new NavigationPage (new MorePage ());

        homepage.BarBackgroundColor = Device.OnPlatform (Color.FromHex (DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarBackgroundColor), Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent);
        homepage.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex(DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarTextColor);
        homepage.Title = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().HomeTitle;
        homepage.Icon = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().HomeImage;

        eventspage.BarBackgroundColor = Device.OnPlatform (Color.FromHex (DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarBackgroundColor), Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent);
        eventspage.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex(DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarTextColor);
        eventspage.Title = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().EventTitle;
        eventspage.Icon = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().EventImage;

        morepage.BarBackgroundColor = Device.OnPlatform (Color.FromHex (DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarBackgroundColor), Color.Transparent, Color.Transparent);
        morepage.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex(DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().BarTextColor);
        morepage.Title = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().MoreTitle;
        morepage.Icon = DependencyService.Get<IContentStrings>().MoreImage;

        Children.Add (homepage);
        Children.Add (eventspage);
        Children.Add (morepage);
    }       
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm able to use a custom renderer or anything. I do not know if I have any options and any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this forum post : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17811/tabbedpage-tabbar-background-color-tint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found was finally able to find the answer after searching the internet a few hours and then coming back to the app on a different day. To change the default from the blue, I changed the UITabbar tint color in the AppDelegate.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle (UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

    LoadApplication (new App ());

    //this changes the default iOS tintcolor for the icon when it's activated
    UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(223, 112, 13);

    return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the active tab icon color with a simple custom iOS renderer like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Orange;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good way of doing it from what I found out. I will also post the solution that I found to work since I have multiple iOS apps using a single base code.